# NG directives not working inside a ng-repeat that is inside another ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a ng-repeat that's inside another ng-repeat. I tried to use ng-class ng-hide and ng-show but it's not working in the child ng-repeat. It does however work inside the parent. For example:

```
<div class="product" ng-repeat="item in category.products">

    <h2 class="product-name">{{item.name}}</h2>

    <ul class="product-variety">
        <li ng-repeat="variation in item.variations" class="{{variation.name}}" ng-hide="true">{{variation.name}}</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

The li with ng-hide does not work. How do i make it work?

Comment: Do you have errors in your console?
I'm pretty sure that this `{{variation..name}}` would throw a parse error

Comment: My bad that's a typo. I downsized the code a little bit so it's more readable but accidentally added another dot.

Comment: It happens some times ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Does `item.variations` actually have something?

Comment: When using ng-hide, ng-class, ng-show etc it doesn't do anything. The item.variation does have data the class="{{variation.name}}" does show the name. So I do see list of variations but when using a ng directive like ng-hide it just doesn't hide it. When used on the parent it does hide.